# How to access properties of a related entity in a DQL query (Doctrine 2)?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, foreign-key-relationship, dql

I have set up a many to one relationship between a schools entity and students entity, I've linked the two together using a manyToOne relationship;

**Students entity:**

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Schools", inversedBy="Students")
 * @JoinColumn(name="school_id", referencedColumnName="school_id")
 */
private $Schools;
```

**Schools entity:**

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Students", mappedBy="Schools")
 */
private $Students;
```

This works as expected.

I am trying to write a query for the Students table which specifies the school_id but I don't know how to specify this within the query;

```
$qb->select('t.position')
    ->from('\Entities\Students', 't')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('t.studentId', ':student_id'))
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('t.Schools.schoolId', ':school_id')) // doesn't work
    ->setParameters(array('student_id' => $this->studentId, 'school_id' => $school_id));
```

I've attempted to access the school id through $Schools property I set up in the student identity but this throws an error.

As a temporary fix I've created a $schoolId property in the Students entity and am using this instead but surely this is not the correct way to do this.

Appreciate the help.

**UPDATE**

I got it to work by changing the line;

```
->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('t.Schools.schoolId', ':school_id')) // doesn't work
```

To:

```
->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('t.Schools', ':school_id'))
```

However the same approach doesn't work with the following query:

```
$qb->select('DISTINCT t.age, s.Schools') // Doesn't work
    ->from('\Entities\Schools', 't')
    ->innerJoin('t.Students', 's')
```

The following error is displayed:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 28 near 'Schools FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

Comment: You have `school_id` in entity declaration and `schoolId` in the query. Check that  your `School` class have $schoolId parameter, not `$school_id`. Also, you have `student_id` parameter, but you set `group_id`. Are you sure about that?

Comment: The differences between school_id and schoolId are just my parameter naming convention, apologies if this is confusing. The group_id was a typo whilst writing the question on here and does not exist in the original code hence I've corrected here.

Comment: I don't think it is naming convention :). Do you have `schoolId` property in `School` class with `@Column` on it? It is essential, as in your query you are using it: `'t.Schools.schoolId`, but your `Students` entry makes it clear, that your DB field is named `school_id`

Comment: Yep I have the following in the School class: http://pastebin.com/64AkSRqL

Comment: I'll try to check it out later, don't have Doctrine 2 at fingertips now

Comment: What's the purpose of that query: `$qb->select('DISTINCT t.age, s.Schools')
    ->from('\Entities\Schools', 't')
    ->innerJoin('t.Students', 's')`

Comment: Those columns contain duplicate values, I don't want to return every occurence the values. I have a where clause in the query which I have ommitted.